# R - Creating new file takes up too much memory

Tags: r, memory, gis, rbind

I'm relatively new and poor at R, and am trying to do something that appears to be giving me trouble.

I have several large spatialpolygonsdataframes that I am trying to combine into 1 spatialpolygonsdataframe. There are 7 and they combine to about 5 GB total. My mac only has 8GB of RAM.

When  I try and create the aggregate spatialpolygonsdataframe R takes an incredibly long time to run and I have to quit out. I presume it is because I do not have sufficient RAM.

my code is simple: aggregate <-rbind(file1,file2,....). Is there a smarter/better way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: You might consider `data.table`: reading your files with `fread` and bind them with `rbindlist`

Comment: Can you confirm it is a RAM constraint by checking it when you run the rbind? https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201538 From my experience R is pretty bad at memory management for large shapefiles.

Answer (score 0):

I would disagree, a major component of reading large datasets isn't RAM capacity (although I would suggest that you upgrade if you can). But rather read/write speeds. Hardware, a HDD at 7200RPM is substantially slower vs. SSD. If you are able to install a SSD and have that as your working directory, I would recommend it.